# Existe um padrão de nomenclatura para enums?

Tags: java, enums, convenções-de-nome

Eu não entendo muito de padrão de nomenclatura de objetos. Estou criando uma `enum` que enumera cargos, por exemplo: gerente, programador, atendente...

Existe um padrão para nomear essa enum? `EnumCargo`, `CargoEnum`,... ???

Comment: Não sei se existe, mas eu prefiro a segunda opção. Em meus projetos e onde trabalho preferimos a estrutura "nome"+"tipo"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sim, existem vários padrões de nomenclatura, na minha visão ainda são uma escolha de estilo. Eu particularmente programo mais em c# e existe um ótimo guia para padronizar que eu sigo.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Já para Java (que faz tempo que não uso na prática) eu geralmente seguia as mesmas recomendações. Na documentação da Oracle eu achei este link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

No entanto, esse link não aborda diretamente as Enums, eu pesquisei um pouco e pelo que encontrei a justificativa é que uma enum é também uma classe e como tal, segue os mesmos padrões de nomenclatura.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

No próprio stackoverflow (inglês) existem vários tópicos sobre isso, seguem dois exemplos abaixo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755955/naming-of-enums-in-java-singular-or-plural

Resumindo, de acordo com essa referência, Enums são classes e podem seguir os mesmos padrões que você adotar para elas.

> Enums are classes and should follow the conventions for classes.
>   Instances of an enum are constants and should follow the conventions
>   for constants.

Deste link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums

Comment: agora sim uma boa resposta! valeu mano!

Comment: Muito bom mesmo!

Answer (score 7):

O padrão de nomenclatura dos `enum`s segue o mesmo padrão da nomenclatura de classes, pelo simples fato do `enum` ser um tipo especial de classe.

Logo, dê o seu nome de uma maneira representativa do seu significado, ou seja, para representar os "cargos", nada melhor que um `enum` de nome "Cargo".

Por exemplo:

```
enum Cargo {
    GERENTE(1), PROGRAMADOR(2), ATENDENTE(3) ;

    private int id;

    Cargo(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class Exemplo {
    public final static int VALOR = 10;
}

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Cargo.GERENTE.getId());
        System.out.println(Exemplo.VALOR);
    }
}
```

Saída:

> 1
>   10

Além de exemplificar uma maneira um pouco mais, digamos, inusitada de usar o `enum`, ou seja, com construtor e *getter*, eu também tento deixar claro que você pode optar por criar uma constante estática dentro de uma classe, para mostrar que a funcionalidade dela é praticamente a mesma, portanto, perceba que não é necessário deixar explicitamente claro que o `enum` é um `enum`, e não uma classe ordinária.

---

Já os valores dos `enums`, de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), `enum` em Java devem ser escritas em maiúsculas, por serem constates.

> Because they are constants, the names of an enum type's fields are in uppercase letters.

Comment: Creio que ele perguntou de um padrão para escrever o nome do enum, no caso a documentação fala dos valores do enum.

Comment: isso mesmo @Dener . O padrão das instancias eu sei, quero saber o padrão de nomenclatura do nome do enum

Comment: public enum NomeDoEnum { INSTANCIA1,INSTANCIA2; }  quero saber o padrão para o NomeDoEnum

Comment: Ainda não concordo... se vc colocar o nome Cargos.. o enum pode ser confundido como uma classe normal por alguem que está mexendo no mesmo projeto que eu

Comment: enums são quase classes, você pode inclusive definir getters para eles, e classes também possuem elementos estáticos que podem ser acessados conforme eu mostrei aqui, vou editar minha resposta para mostrar

Comment: @PedroLaini, ENUM pode conter construtores, getter e settters como o Math falou são quase classes.

Comment: Achei uma referência em um livro que afirma que enum é um tipo especial de classe, vou embasar minha resposta, mas já editei para mostrar o que eu afirmei acima, @PedroLaini

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino setters não, pois seus valores são constantes :)

Comment: Bem lembrado @Math

Answer (score 1):

Usando como base essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069863/3861347) do SOen:

> Devem ser em letra maiúscula por serem constantes

```
 public enum Cargo {
    GERENTE, PROGRAMADOR, DBA, ARQUITETO
}
```

A [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) não cita um padrão todos os exemplos tratam apenas do tipo que será representado pelo `Enum`:

```
public enum Trabalhador {
    CLT, PJ, ESTAGIARIO
}
```

Comment: O padrão das instancias eu sei, quero saber o padrão de nomenclatura do nome do enum

Comment: observe a chamada  `inserirTrabalhador(trabalhador.getProfissao(Cargo.GERENTE)` e a chamada `inserirTrabalhador(trabalhador.getProfissao(EnumCargo.GERENTE)`

Comment: esse comentário não foi uma resposta pra minha dúvida

Comment: Editei @PedroLaini

Comment: Colocando o nome assim o enum pode ser confundido como uma classe normal, quando outra pessoa está mexendo no projeto

Comment: @PedroLaini, um enum é considerado uma classe especial. O acesso ao Enum é diferente, Cargo.GERENTE, uma classe normal cargo.getGerente(), não vejo como confundir as duas.